# Get Claim Value/AppRole Name from AppRoleId for Service Principals (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to get all app role assignments for all service principals.

I use the following command to get the app role assignments per service principal.

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId <id>
```

That returns:

```
AppRoleId            : df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214
CreatedDateTime      : 2022-11-24 08:32:38
DeletedDateTime      :
Id                   : <Id>
PrincipalDisplayName : <PrincipalDisplayName>
PrincipalId          : <PrincipalId>
PrincipalType        : ServicePrincipal
ResourceDisplayName  : Microsoft Graph
ResourceId           : <ResourceId>
AdditionalProperties : {}
```

I get everything I need but the claim value/app role name. In this case it's 'User.Read.All'.

Is there a way to get/lookup these names for the Microsofts API's that you can assign permissions for in Azure portal using preferably Powershell? Those would be GraphAPI, Office 365 Management APIs, etc.

Comment: Hi @ChristofferL Are you okay with the AzureAD PowerShell module to fetch the results?

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan. Is it that one that will be deprecated? I rather not use anything that will soon be deprecated. If it's not that one, I can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch all the app roles assigned to all the service principals you can use the script below:

**Script:**

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.Read.All"

$Apps = Get-MgApplication
$ServicePrincipals = Get-MgServicePrincipal -All
$RolesList = @()

foreach ($sp in $ServicePrincipals) {
    $RolesList += $sp.AppRoles
}

$Data = @()
foreach ($App in $Apps) {
    foreach ($Access in $App.RequiredResourceAccess) {

        foreach ($Permission in $Access.ResourceAccess) {
            $PermissionName = $null

            if ($Permission.Type -eq 'Role') {
                $PermissionName = ($RolesList | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $Permission.Id }).Value
            }

            if ($PermissionName) {
                $Data += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'Application Display Name' = $App.DisplayName
                    'Permission Type'          = $Permission.Type
                    'Permission Value'         = $PermissionName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$Data | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the script. It can only lookup two unique permissions (User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All) from the 144 unique permissions added into $RolesList.

Comment: @ChristofferL Whether you need only to list `user.read.all` and `user.readwrite.all` permission from the service principal?

Comment: I will need them all. The $PermissionName from the $Data variable is empty for all permissions but User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All. The rest doesn't exist in $RolesList and the PermissionName can't be found.

Comment: @ChristofferL the above script works for all application API permissions also can you paste your output screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot of output: https://imgur.com/a/AawuJeL

Comment: @ChristofferL have you tried as same as my script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255617/discussion-between-christofferl-and-venkatesan).

Comment: Figured it out. Need to add the "-All" flag to to get all service principals.